# Double usage of <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/> in transform

Tags: xslt

I have a transform which is (simplified version) something like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="head">
        <xsl:element name="head">
            <xsl:element name="title">
                <xsl:text>Transformed document</xsl:text>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
     </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="body">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It transforms sample HTML document

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<html xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Sample page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" type="text/css"/>
        <meta name="author" content="John Doe"></meta>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Header</h1>
        <p>Some text</p>
        <p>Some other text</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

To:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><html lang="en" xml:lang="en">
    <head><title>Transformed document</title></head>
    <body>
        <h1>Header</h1>
        <p>Some text</p>
        <p>Some other text</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

I can't understand why I need to call apply-templates twice. As I understand, the first one should copy everything to the output (including head, which should be overwritten), and the second one should copy only body (which is what I want). However, both seem to be necessary. If I remove that from body, I have only head in output, if I remove first one, I get only extracted text from nodes, not the nodes.

Why in the following example is `<xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>` needed twice and is it possible to simplify that example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is **not** calling `xsl:apply-templates`twice, but having an entire template that's redundant.

Since you're not changing `body` in any way, you can leave it to be processed by the *identity transform* template (your first template), and remove the last template:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="head">
        <xsl:element name="head">
            <xsl:element name="title">
                <xsl:text>Transformed document</xsl:text>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
     </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

BTW, you can also simplify the template matching `head` to:

```
<xsl:template match="head">
    <head>
        <title>Transformed document</title>
    </head>
</xsl:template>
```

No need to use `xsl:element` when the name of the element is known in advance.